# Unknown error while moving from one controller to another controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, presentviewcontroller

In my app i am getting unknown error,while moving from one controller to another by using this code,

```
-(IBAction)backQA:(id)sender
{
UIAlertController *alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"Are You Sure Quit The Exam!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


 UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
 ContestViewController *contestVC =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContestVC"];
 [self presentViewController:contestVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action)     {

}];
[alert addAction:ok];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When i click on my Ok action i am getting error.

Here is the screen shot,

[image]

Any help?

Here is the my setMainBanner Method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    @try
    {
       if((NSNull *)[contestDict objectForKey:@"mainbanner"] != [NSNull null])
        {
            if([[contestDict objectForKey:@"mainbanner"] length] > 0)
             {
               NSString *mainBannerimage = [contestDict objectForKey:@"mainbanner"];
               NSString *bannerImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.karo.com/APP/banners/%@", mainBannerimage];
               NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:bannerImageURL];
            [mainBanner sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilepic_bg"]];
              }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
 @catch (NSException *exception)
 {

 }
}
```

Comment: how you present view controllers?

Comment: @balkaransingh by using story board identifier.

Comment: The error is coming from the `setMainBanner:` method of your `ContestViewController`. Update your question with the code of the method.

Comment: @rmaddy see my updated question.

Comment: That's your `viewDidLoad` method, not the `setMainBanner:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry i don't have setMainBanner method separately.

Comment: Disable breakpoints and run the app. See if you get a full error message in the debugger console. Update your question with the error.

Comment: @rmaddy i disabled my break points it is working fine.can u tell me the reason for that?

Comment: Your app was never crashing. You have a breakpoint set. The debugger was simply stopping at your breakpoint. Remove the breakpoint.

Comment: @rmaddy ok. thanks for u r help:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle
                              message:alertMessage
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction 
            actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                      style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                    {
                      NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                    }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction 
            actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                    {
                      NSLog(@"OK action");
                    }];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];
```

Finally we can present the alert view controller as with any other view controller:

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: 1) Because it has nothing to do with the issue. The problem is with presenting the next view controller when the user taps the OK button. 2) You just posted some code with no explanation. What was wrong and how does your answer fix it?

Comment: @rmaddy Ok. I didn't read question carefully. I thought its related to ok button functionality or not proper implementation.

Comment: You can delete you answer.

Answer (score -2):

why you are using presentViewController  use this

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```